# Installing provisioning profiles and certificates on a VSTS macOS agent to sign a Cordova application

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've been working on an Ionic/Cordova application and I am trying to create continuous delivery mechanism as per VSTS standards.My workflow is as per the image below. I have uploaded my provisioning profiles files as secure files in the SafeFiles feature provided by VSTS and the installation steps are all linked to the mentioned files. However, when I am trying to install a provisioning profile so that I can build and create an archive for upload to the ITunesConnect portal, the process returns an error with a "value cannot be null" message. Without this step I cannot sign the application, so skipping it is not really an option.

[image: VSTS workphase flow]

However I keep getting the error below. Any assistance would be truly appreciated

[image: Error provided]

Comment: Set system.debug variable to true and queue build, then post the detail log here.

Comment: Can you share the detailed settings for that step?